# Informal Meeting with Team Prior to Starting Work - what is that?

Tags: australia

I've been invited to an informal meeting with my hiring manager and some members of my team a week prior to commencing work with the firm. Just a little background, I'm hired as a local expat in Australia and have relocated over from Singapore.

Is this common? And if so, what is the point of it?

Negatively, I'm thinking that they are reconsidering their decision and I'm quite stressed out by it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like the purpose of this meeting is to introduce you and your new coworkers to each other in an environment where you can talk without the pressures of a normal work day.

It's a good thing, no need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

It's a meet and greet and an opportunity to chat with the people you'll be working with in an informal, stress free setting.